# How to remove the MessageMediaWebPage error?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telethon

When a link preview is present in a message, this error occurs:

```
Cannot use <telethon.tl.types.MessageMediaWebPage object at 0x0000019BA349CC20> as file
```

I don't quite understand how to get rid of it. I tried to do this in my code, but the error still appears:

```
async def send_media(message, destination_channel_id):
    try:
        if message.media and isinstance(message.media, (MessageMediaPhoto, MessageMediaDocument)):
            return await client.send_file(destination_channel_id, caption=message.text, file=message.media)
        elif message.media and isinstance(message.media, MessageMediaWebPage):
            return
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
```

I'm using `telethon 1.34`

I will be very grateful for your help.